# Self referencing entities with automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper, dto

I have came across a problem where i need to map self referencing table from EF6 to DTO.

This is the table :

[image]

The Entity looks like this :

```
public partial class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        this.ChildPages = new HashSet<Page>();
    }

    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsList { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentPageId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Page> ChildPages { get; set; }
    public virtual Page ParentPage { get; set; }
}
```

The DTO Model looks like this :

```
 public class PageViewModel
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsList { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PageViewModel> ChildPages { get; set; }
    public virtual PageViewModel ParentPage { get; set; }

}
```

Automapper config looks like this:

```
config.CreateMap<Page, PageViewModel>().MaxDepth(8)
```

However when I run this code :

```
var pages = DB.Pages.ProjectTo<PageViewModel>().ToList();
```

I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type 'PageViewModel' appears in two
>   structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to
>   Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same
>   query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and
>   those properties are set in the same order.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this one? Just dealing with the same problem

Comment: @quin61 hi. No, unfortunately i ended up using lazy loading instead.

Comment: yeah, me too. Maybe it's the right way to do that